# handling click event on container and contained html elements

Tags: html, event-handling, jquery

I am using JQuery and I have a container (Div) sized 100 by 30,
and an image that is placed within it (sized 20x20).

I want some event handling to take place when the div is clicked
and different event handling to happen when the image is clicked.

I do not want the handler for the div to fire when the click is on the image.

how am I supposed to handle event binding and event propagation ?

Thanks

Comment: Thanks to all 3 of you. 
I wish i could accept all your answers. 
I chose the most complete one even though it came in 5 min after the other ones as I appreciate the extra effort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either `return false;` to stop propagation or use [`event.stopPropagation()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/):

```
<div id="mydiv">
    <p>Your div</p>
    <img alt="your image" />
    <span>A span inside the div</span>
</div>
```

```
$("#mydiv").click(function(){
    alert("You clicked on the div element");
});

$("#mydiv > img").click(function(e){
    alert("You clicked on a img inside the div element");
    return false; /* will prevent the browser default action! */
});
$("#mydiv > span").click(function(e){
    alert("You clicked on a span inside the div element");
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

See also:

- [demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/yUPLU/)
- [jQuery documentation: `.bind()`](http://api.jquery.com/bind/):

> Returning `false` from a handler is equivalent to calling both `.preventDefault()` and `.stopPropagation()` on the event object.

Answer (score 1):

You need to stop the propagation of the `click` event on the image:

```
$("#yourImage").click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    //Do stuff on image click
});
$("#yourDiv").click(function() {
    //Do stuff on div click
});
```

Since DOM events bubble up the tree, any click on a descendant element (the `img` in your case) bubbles up through any ancestor elements (the `div` in your case). By calling `stopPropagation` on the event object, this is prevented and the event stays where it is.

Note that you could return `false` from the event handler to have the same effect, but this would also have the potentially undesiered side effects of preventing the default browser action of the event.

Answer (score 1):

The click event is handled with the [.click()](http://api.jquery.com/click/) function.  You select something and then apply click, like this:

```
$("#mydiv").click(function(event){
    //do whatever you want when the div is clicked.
});
```

To stop an event from "bubbling" or propagating, inside that click function you can either finish with a `return false` or use the [event.stopPropagation()](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/) function on the `event` that's passed in.  You would want to apply this on your image to stop the click from propagating up to the div.